# Kendo cascading dropdown loading dropdown based on other drop down selection

Tags: kendo-ui

I am planning of using a cascading kendo drop down. 
Drop down 1 - Countries - it will list down all the countries.
Drop down 2 - States - Based on the selection of the country I have to show the states here.

The data for both are loaded from my api controllers. I referred to this link
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist.html

But, I need to pass the first selected value to the second drop down.
PLease suggest the best way to do it. Examples would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use events for that
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/events.html

```
.Events(e =>
            {
  e.Change("change").Select("select").Open("open").Close("close").DataBound("dataBound");
            })

 <script>
      function change() {
          // get a reference to the dropdown list
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlistTwoForStates").data("kendoDropDownList");
//Write your logic here to bind data for thie dropdown
// disable the dropdown list
dropdownlist.enable(true);
        };
    </script>
```